# Vue Component default data value overrides what I set in beforeRouteUpdate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I use vue-router's beforeRouteEnter and beforeRouteUpdate to fetch data from a REST API

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>{{ league.name }} </h2>
    <user-list :users="league.leaderboard" type="list"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UserList from '../components/UserList.vue'
import League from '../model/League'
export default {

    components: {
        UserList
    },

    data() {
        return {
            league: { name: 'init', leaderboard: [] },
        }
    },

    methods: {
        setLeague(league) {
            this.league = league
        }
    },

    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
        League.$find(to.params.league)
            .then(league => {
                next(vm => {
                    vm.league = league
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if(err.response && err.response.status == 404)
                    next('/404')
                else
                    next(vm => vm.error = err)
            })
    },

    watch: {
        league() {
            console.log('league changed ', this.league)
        }
    },

    beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
        this.league = null
        League.$find(to.params.league)
            .then(league => {
                this.setLeague(league)
                console.log('beforeUpdate: ', this.league)
                next()
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if(err.response && err.response.status == 404)
                    next('/404')
                else {
                    this.error = err
                    next()
                }
            })
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

the beforeRouteEnter guard works as expected.

There is a common case in my application where the route changes from `/leagues/1` to `/leagues/1`, so my component gets reused and the beforeRouteUpdate guard gets fired. There, the rest data gets fetched and the league data is set via this.setLeague(). The console.log call outputs the new league data. However, when next() gets called, ````this.league``` is overriden to the *default* value (name: 'init' etc.) which I specified in the data function. I have no idea why.

I basically adapted this code directly from the vue docs [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation).

An interesting thing to note is that the `this.league = null` triggers the watcher, whilst `this.setLeague` does not. Also, the output logged in beforeUpdateRoute is not a vue observer, but the plain league object. I tried changing the `this.setLeague` call to `this.league = league`, which didn't help.

Comment: what do mean by changes from /leagues/1 to /leagues/1

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have same right now (

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so I created new Test component, and started testing it. I have found that `created()`, `mounted()`, `data()` hooks fire twice, what means that instead of caching Component, router recreates it each time. Then I have looked in App component, and save the reason of it. I have assigned unique key for each route, so it would use different instances of Component instead of one for each path, like /test/page/1 and /test/page/2. So I have removed it, and all now working as expected

So if you see same code as below in you main Component, replace it with last one.

```
<template>
  <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
</template>
```

---

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```